# Is it possible to move the keyboard to the top of the screen?

Tags: swype

One of the biggest advantages to the Swype keyboard is the ability to effectively type with only one hand. However this dosent work very well since the keyboard is at the bottom of the screen. Is there any way to move the keyboard to the top of the screen only when on portrait mode so that I can grip the phone with one hand and type with my thumb on the top of the screen where my thumb has more range of motion?

Comment: On other note, wouldn't your hand obstructs the screen if the keyboard is on top?

Comment: Lie Ryan has a good point, and I don't see how holding it towards the top instead of towards the bottom would improve your thumb's range of motion.

Comment: I'm not sure how you hold your phone when I hold it my thumb clears the entire bottom screen perfectly. Try it yourself, bring up the keyboard and then flip the phone upside down and grip it in one hand and you'll see that you can still see the bottom screen just fine, well, depends on the size of your phone and hands I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no setting to do this.  It would appear there is also no supported method for a keyboard developer to set where their keyboard is drawn (see [KeyboardView on android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html)).